# Wave Analytic - Group by Clause Issue

Tags: analytics-cloud

I have deployed external CSV file successfully on wave analytic which contains both alphabetic and numeric values under the fields.

Under lenses, group by clause only shows fields which contains alphabetic values but not showing fields which contains numeric value.

Please let me know how to get fields which contains numeric values in group by clause.

Thanks,
Inderjeet

Comment: you can probably upload numbers as text and then try

Answer (score 1):

**group by clause** works only for **text** fields. 
**Measure** works for **numeric** values

You can't group numeric fields in Wave. The only way to do that is, while uploading the CSV change that field type as text(even though it is numeric).  If you want do measure operations and group by operations on same field, you should clone the numeric field as a Text field.

Remember, 
group by --> text fields 
measure --> numeric values.

Only exception to this is, **count** attribute in measure actually works for text fields too